# Compiler does not complain that I catch an exception that can never be thrown

Tags: java, exception

I am reading a More precise rethrows in java 7 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html which says

> In detail, in Java SE 7 and later, when you declare one or more
>   exception types in a catch clause, and rethrow the exception handled
>   by this catch block, the compiler verifies that the type of the
>   rethrown exception meets the following conditions:
>
> ```
> The try block is able to throw it.
> There are no other preceding catch blocks that can handle it.
> It is a subtype or supertype of one of the catch clause's exception parameters.
> ```

so i wrote a program to test it .

```
public class MorePreciseRethrow {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try {
            foo("First");
        } catch (FirstException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecondException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void foo(String exceptionName) throws FirstException, SecondException{
        try{
            if(StringUtils.equals("First",exceptionName)){
                throw new FirstException();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw e;
        }
    }
}

class FirstException extends Exception{

}

class SecondException extends Exception{

}
```

but this doesn't generate even a compiler warning with jdk7.
Now my try block is never able to throw SecondException, but my compiler didn't check it . Is the mentioned line in doc is wrong or am i doing some mistake ?

Answer (score 3):

The compiler only checks if the method header

```
private static void foo(String exceptionName) throws FirstException, SecondException
```

declairs thr exception.

You can have multiple implementations of methods so one implementation can throw the exeption and one not. but both must bedeclaired.

Answer (score 2):

In java, there is no requirement that the code in a method that declares that it `throws` an exception actually be able to throw it.

This makes sense, because the method may be implementing an interface, but the implementation happens to not throw it, or it could allow for future expansion to an implementation/subclass that does throw it.

Comment: For a non-static method, you might throw this checked exception later by subclassing the class and overriding the method. + 1

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the compilation error that documentation is talking about, you need to use a [multiple catch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html). Something like,

```
private static void foo(String exceptionName) throws FirstException,
        SecondException {
    try {
        throw new FirstException();
    } catch (FirstException | SecondException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Creates an `UnreachableCodeBlock` for `SecondException` in Java 7+.

Comment: that is a different exception

Comment: It's a compile error, not an `Exception`. And (again) your link is for `multi-catch`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The doc states "one or more exception types" and in fact this works without a (real) multiple catch if you only try to catch `SecondException` which will never be thrown here.